# Magento 2 coupon add/remove event listener

Tags: magento, magento2

I need to add event on cart to add/remove coupon.
I created event listener `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost` this working perfect on page - `/checkout/cart/`. 
But on next page - `/checkout/#payment` this not working. I can't found event to add listener.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

`controller_action_predispatch` events are automatically generated based on route or full action name of the request.

If you search for `controller_action_predispatch` you'll find that these events are dispatched in `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::dispatch(RequestInterface)`.

- `/checkout/cart/couponPost` is located in `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost`, which is a controller
- `/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/coupons/{coupon}` is not a controller but a REST API, because of this it's "located" in `/vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml` and defines the "`/V1/carts/mine/coupons/:couponCode` endpoint which in turn references `Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface::set(int, string)`

If you want you can write a plugin for `Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface::set(int, string)`, but without knowing your exact use-case I can't say whether this is a good solution or if you might be better off with another event or observer.